# How can I refactor classes in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I have test code written in Python, using classes.

The test environment has two types of hosts - app hosts, where applications run, and storage hosts, where storage components run.

I have two classes, each representing the type of host:

```
class AppHost_Class(object):
    def __init_(self, ip_address):
        # etc.

    # This method handles interfacing with the application
    def application_service(self):

    # This method handles the virtual storage component
    def virtual_storage(self):

    # This method handles caching
    def cache_handling(self):


class Storage_Server_Class(object):
    def __init_(self, ip_address):

    # This method handles interfacing with the storage process
    def storage_handling(self):

    # This method handles interfacing with the disk handling processes
    def disk_handling(self):
```

The problem is that the topology can change.

Topology #1 is this:
- Application Host runs
   * Application processes
   * Virtual storage processes
   * Cache processes

- Storage Host runs

  - Storage processes
  - Disk handling processes

My current test code handles Topology #1

However, we also want to support another Topology (Topology #2)

- Application Host runs

  - Application processes
- Storage Host runs

  - Virtual storage processes
  - Cache processes
  - Storage processes
  - Disk handling processes

How can I refactor the classes so that for Topology 1, the classes and its methods are the same, but for Topology 2, the `Storage_Server_Class` gets some of the methods from the `AppHost_Class`?

I was thinking of making a child class like this:

```
class Both_Class(AppHost_Class, Storage_Server_Class):
```

But I don't want to do this because I don't want the `applcation_service` method  to be available to `Both_Class`.

Is there a way to just map a few methods in `AppHost_Class` into the `Storage_Server_Class`?

Comment: Can't you just put the methods to be shared into another class which `AppHost_Class` inherits from and introduces the `application_service` method to, and then inherit from that other class and `Storage_Server_Class` for your `Both_Class`. Although - does it really matter if you have that method available in both class?

Comment: That would be one way to do it Jon.  But it would require some code changes because to make the example, I simplified it.  These classes don't have 2-3 methods/attributes.  It's more like 30+ methods and 30+ attributes.

This would be a major recoding effort.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a class B that shares exactly one method defined in class A:

```
class A:
    def a1(self):
        pass
    def a2(self):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self, instance_of_a):
        self.a2 = instance_of_a.a2

a = A()
B(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want three base classes. One for `App` stuff, one for `VirtualStorage` (and cache) stuff and one for `Storage` (and disk) stuff. Then you can make child classes for your two topologies that mix the desired methods together.

For topology 1, you have a class that inherits from both the `App` and the `VirtualStorage` base classes (and you use the `Storage` base class unmodified). For topology 2, you create a class that inherits from the `VirtualStorage` and the `Storage` base classes and use the `App` base class unmodified.

Example code:

```
class App:
    def do_app_stuff(self):
        pass

class VirtualStorage:
    def do_virtual_storage_stuff(self):
        pass

class Storage:
    def do_storage_stuff(self):
        pass

# topology 1
class Top1App(App, VirtualStorage):
    pass

Top1Storage = Storage

# topology 2
Top2App = App

class Top2Storage(VirtualStorage, Storage):
    pass
```

You might not need the aliased names for the base classes you're using directly in the different topologies, I just threw those in to make it look extra nice.

Answer (score 1):

Split the methods up into three classes then combine as needed.

```
#class NetworkObject(object):    # Python 2.7
class NetworkObject:
    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        self.ip_address = ip_address

class AppHost(NetworkObject):
    def application_service(self):
        print('app service', self.ip_address)

class Storage_Server(NetworkObject):
    def storage_handling(self):
        print('storage handler', self.ip_address)
    def disk_handling(self):
        print('disk handler', self.ip_address)

class Foo(object):
    def virtual_storage(self):
        print('virtual storage', self.ip_address)
    def cache_handling(self):
        print('cache handling', self.ip_address)

topology_1, topology_2 = True, False

# Topology 1
if topology_1:
    class AppHost_Class(AppHost, Foo):
        pass
    class Storage_Server_Class(Storage_Server):
        pass

# Topology 2
if topology_2:
    class AppHost_Class(AppHost):
        pass
    class Storage_Server_Class(Storage_Server, Foo):
        pass
```

---

Another option would be to define the two classes with the methods they will always include,

```
#class NetworkObject(object):    # Python 2.7
class NetworkObject:
    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        self.ip_address = ip_address

class A(NetworkObject):
    def application_service(self):
        print('app service', self.ip_address)

class B(NetworkObject):
    def storage_handling(self):
        print('storage handler', self.ip_address)
    def disk_handling(self):
        print('disk handler', self.ip_address)
```

... define methods you would like to mix and match

```
def virtual_storage(self):
    print('virtual storage', self.ip_address)

def cache_handling(self):
    print('cache handling', self.ip_address)
```

... and conditionally add the methods to the classes

```
topology = 1
if topology == 1:
    A.virtual_storage = virtual_storage
    A.cache_handling = cache_handling

if topology == 2:
    B.virtual_storage = virtual_storage
    B.cache_handling = cache_handling
```

You may want to define the *extra* methods in the parent/base class but have them raise an exception unless a topology has been *applied*

```
#class NetworkObject(object):    # Python 2.7
class NetworkObject:
    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        self.ip_address = ip_address
    def virtual_storage(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def cache_handling(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```